# Redis Cluster/Sentinel on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, redis, redis-cluster, redis-sentinel, redis-server

I currently have some redis running on different VM's for different applications and I would like to centralize it, to facilitate maintenance and have high availability.
I'm using TCPIngress from the kong ingress controller

With that, I'm trying to create a redis cluster on an existing kubernetes, with a scenario to later create a mirrored productive environment.

But I couldn't get it to work correctly from examples found on forums or even using Redis, Bitnami or even Helm documentation.

Using the "Another Redis Desktop Manager" tool, some type of error always occurred, either to insert a key or not to display the created key.

I've been looking all day and haven't found a solution that works, whether it's sentinel or cluster, I'm already giving up on migrating the service to k8s.
Has anyone managed to do this and/or know of any recent tutorials that actually work?

Answer (score 0):

for Redis Cluster in k8s, you can add connection via "SSH+Cluster" on "Another Redis Desktop Manager", like this https://github.com/qishibo/AnotherRedisDesktopManager#1-how-to-connect-to-redis-cluster-in-internal-network-such-as-docker-lan-aws , then everything goes well

usually I config the "SSH host" with a host machine which runs k8s

I hope it can help you